# How can the SAMD21 chip knows when the on-board NINA W102 restarts

Tags: esp32, spi, arduino-nano-33-iot

I am building a project that requires the SAMD21 microcontroller to send a `resetToFactory` signal to the NINA W102 on Arduino Nano 33 IoT. My plan is that, once the W102 receives the signal will do NVS formatting and restart itself, and then I need the SAMD21 to restart afterward by an event triggering from the W102(W102 needs to finish the restart cycle first), see the figure.
[image]

The communication protocol is SPI as the WIFININA lib does.

I have few attempts by trying to read the GPIO voltage from W102, however, it doesn't work because SPI on SAMD21 side will just hang until the W102 finished the restart even though I remove the `waitForSlaveReady()` for receiving the reply, so I can't get any event triggering.

By the way, I can't simply use the `RESET_N` because the program won't know to do the NVS formatting first.

Does anyone have related experience or ideas? Thank you very much.

Best regards,

Edwin Lu

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this later I post the question.

The solution is using the fact which SPI on the SAMD21 will hang while W102 restarts, so I just set the SAMD21 restart immediately after the program continues.

Best regards,

Edwin Lu